# SSRS DataSet Schema changes to dbo

Tags: sql, schema, ssrs-2012

I am having a problem with my Shared DataSet not retaining the Schema name in the query.  This was working but I must have changed something and not realized the effect of what i did.

I have a view, Incident, in a schema called 'PublicData', it has the same name as a table in the dbo schema. I ALWAYS want to use that view when I run my report and have added 'publicData' in the query of the shared dataset.  However after I save it the query designer drops the schema and it reverts to dbo and then my query fails because the fields are not named the same in the view.

Any suggestions on where to look or what to change so the report works correctly?  Other helpful information:  I have a Database user that is used to connect to the database and only has permissions to the view.  The Data Source is set up to use that user.

Thanks for any guidance.
Leslie

Comment: Is the publicData there in your current data source? are you able to run the query from query designer?

Answer (score 0):

Is **PublicData** you **default** schema? The **Query Designer** in BIDS may be **ass**u**me**ing that you don't need the schema since it's the default.

You might be able to add it in manually from the **Shared Dataset Properties** window without going into **Query Designer**.

In this example, **dbo** is my default. If I go into **Query Designer** and exit it will remove the **dbo**. If I add the **dbo** in the Query text box, it will remain.

[image]

Comment: Yes it is in the Shared DataSet that I am having the issue.  I change what you have highlighted in red to PublicData.  I go to the query designer and run the query.  It works.  After I exit the dataset and go back in my PublicData schema is no longer in the query (neither is dbo) and when I try to run the query again I get an error that my fields don't exist (which is correct since it is selecting from the dbo table and not the PublicData view)